# How to increase the 255 characters limit of a text box in Survey SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

Is there any way to increase the 255 characters limit of a choice type question or a text box, in a Survey SharePoint 2013? I mention I do not have access to the Central Administration.
Thank you!

[Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nqFx.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpiYd.png)

Comment: Go to survey setting and change column type to multiple line of text and you can add content beyond 255 characters.

Comment: I cannot change the type of the question, because the task is to create a survey which has choice questions with looooong questions and answers you can choose.

Comment: I didnt face any issue while creating question which was very loooooooong.. around 1000 characters.. on SP 2013.. Can you provide screenshot of your issue ?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nqFx.png 
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpiYd.png